# typescript: application is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

Когда пытаюсь создать экземпляр класса, вылетает ошибка

> TypeError: application_module__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a is not a constructor

**index.ts**

```
import Application from 'application-module';

const app = new Application();

app.start();
```

**application-module**

```
import { IApp } from 'common-module';

export default class Application implements IApp {
  routes: any[];
  actions: any[];
  constructor() {
    this.routes = [];
    this.actions = [];
  }
}
```

**IApp** (мало ли)

```
export interface IApp extends Module {
  routes: any[];
  actions: any[];
}
```

Пробовал нагуглить - обычно все из-за того, что пытаются импортировать `export class A` как `import A`, но здесь этого нет.

Comment: @mix Это ж ведь не присвоение, а декларация свойств. Присвоение осуществляется в конструкторе. Даже если переписать так, то будет ошибка `'any[]' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

Comment: @mix дело в том, что этот модуль как раз-таки и лежит в `node_modules`

Comment: У вас `application-module` лежит в `node_modules`?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko да

Comment: Тогда я хз. Будем ждать спецов.

Comment: Приведенный код должен работать нормально. Попробуй подключать библиотеку не из node_modules, а напрямую, если код заработает, то проблема в том, как именно собирается билиотека

Comment: @Grundy изначально весь код лежал в одном проекте и все работало

Comment: Значит очевидно проблема именно в том, как ты делаешь библиотеку. Поэтому нужно добавить больше информации с этой стороны

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы разрешить эту проблему, мне пришлось подправить `webpack.config.js` и заставить его смотреть в `node_modules/my-custom-component`.

Comment: Можете написать что именно вы добавили в свой webpack.config. У меня аналогичная проблема. У меня написан класс (на typescript) и импортирован как модуль в другом файле, а далее эта ошибка где создается instance:
 `new MyClass() `